# Facebook strategy with sapper and polka

Tags: passport.js, svelte, passport-facebook, sapper

I need to make a connection with polka (not Express) and using a passport-facebook strategy. On my serverjs:

```
var app = polka();
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb){
    return cb(null, profile);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, cb){
    return cb(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new Strategy({
    clientID: *****,
    clientSecret: '******',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/login/facebook/callback',
    //campo opzionale, specifico gli oggetti del profilo che voglio tornato
    profile: ['id', 'displayName']
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //Check the DB to find a User with the profile.id
    User.findOne({ uid: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);  // handle errors!
      }
      if (user) {
        console.log("find user!", user);
        done(null, user); //Login if User already exists
      } else { //else create a new User
        user = new User({
          uid: profile.id, //pass in the id and displayName params from Facebook
          name: profile.displayName
        });
        user.save(function(err) { //Save User if there are no errors else redirect to login.
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);  // handle errors!
          } else {
            console.log("saving user ...");
            done(null, user);
            console.log("user", user);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
));

app 
    //va sempre messo prima di passport.session
    .use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }))
    .use(passport.initialize())
    .use(passport.session())

    //definisco le rotte

    //rotta di login
    .get('/login/facebook',
        passport.authenticate('facebook')
    )

    //callback

    .get('/login/facebook/callback',

        //da confermare se è supportato il fialureRedirect
        //passport.authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect: '/'}),
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect: '/'}),
        function(req, res){
            res.writeHead(302, {
                'Location': '/admin/menu',
                'content-type': 'document'
            });
            res.end();
        }
    )

    .use(
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        formData.parse(options),
        formData.format(),
        //formData.stream(),
        formData.union(),
        json(),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
```

When i make the login the console shows also that i'm already logged in (it created also a object on the mongodbclient and it's also finded), but the problem is that redirect me on some url with

```
http://localhost:3000/login/facebook/callback?code=AQBBJIV61HxahPCtWBgMR23OMpU8MXfxDcD3BeRDTUw2rK5FvTnXq5n...
```

with a message "profile is not defined"

and on the console i have this on pending

[image]

Comment: Two things: **1**. in your passport strat, the callback route is `/auth/facebook/callback` but you serve `/login/facebook/callback`, that's likely the source of your 404 **2**. I don't believe `res.redirect` is a valid method for Polka servers, you have to use a combination of `res.writeHead` (with a redirection status code and redirection url) and `res.end`.

Comment: thanks for the correction about 404. Now i'm tryng to use writeHead and res.end but it makes service-worker error.I'm tryng..

Comment: I edited the first topic with the problem that i have now

Comment: Looks to me like a server error (code 500) on the Facebook end. Perhaps double check that the protocol/address used are correct, and that your credentials (client ID & secret) are valid? I also edited your question to hide these. You should probably set both of these values as ENV variables and read them with `process.env` instead of having them showing in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On serializeUser you return profile that is never declared you have to use:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb){
   return cb(null, user);
});
```